# How to split up code for better readability?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I want to clean up my code for better readability and put some code in extra js-files but nothing I've tried has worked.

It's a SubApp and part of a larger Project (Shopware) that is still using ExtJs 4.1.

I have a "main/window.js" that extends 'Ext.window.Window'.
initComponent looks like this:

```
initComponent: function () {
   //...
   me.dockedItems = [
      me.createTopToolbar(),
   ];
   //...
}
```

createTopToolbar is a Method inside "main/window.js" that return a Ext.toolbar.Toolbar with some elements.

My goal is to put this method in an extra file.

I tried to create a new static/singleton class like this

```
Ext.define('myapp.myplugin.view.main.Toptoolbar', {
   singleton: true,
   createTopToolbar: function(){
      // ...
      return toolbar;
   }
```

But inside "main/window.js" i cannot call it using myapp.myplugin.view.main.Toptoolbar.createTopToolbar(), or main.Toptoolbar.createTopToolbar()

In app.js i tried to include it like this

```
views: [
    'main.Window',
    'main.Toptoolbar',
],
```

but it doesnt work.

I have no experience with ExtJs and search for hours...hope someone can help me.

Thank you

## Edit

To answer the question why i'm building the toolbar within a function.
The whole functions looks like this:

```
createTopToolbar: function () {
    var me = this;

    var shopStore = Ext.create('Shopware.apps.Base.store.Shop');

    shopStore.filters.clear();
    shopStore.load({
        callback: function(records) {
            shopCombo.setValue(records[0].get('id'));
        }
    });

    var shopCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        name: 'shop-combo',
        fieldLabel: 'Shop',
        store: shopStore,
        labelAlign: 'right',
        labelStyle: 'margin-top: 2px',
        queryMode: 'local',
        valueField: 'id',
        editable: false,
        displayField: 'name',
        listeners: {
            'select': function() {
                if (this.store.getAt('0')) {
                    me.fireEvent('changeShop');
                }
            }
        }
    });

    var toolbar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
        dock: 'top',
        ui: 'shopware-ui',
        items: [
            '->',
            shopCombo
        ]
    });

    return toolbar;
```

}

And i dont want the whole code inside my "main/window.js".
I'm not sure using the xtype solution provided by Jaimee in this context because i dont realy extend 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar'. I just need a "wrapper" for my "shopCombo" code and return 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar' with shopCombo as an item.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're building the toolbar within a function, could you explain the motivation for that?

Comment: @Jaimee I have edit my original question to explain my motivation.

Comment: There are two good patterns for this. You could create the toolbar as a new view that you refer to by xtype, or add it as a mixin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the [toolbar](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar) as you would any other view, and create an 'xtype' to add it to your window.

```
Ext.define('myapp.myplugin.view.main.Toptoolbar', {
   extends: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
   xtype: 'mytoptoolbar',
   dock: 'top',
   ui: 'shopware-ui',
   items :[
      '->',
      {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        name: 'shop-combo',
        fieldLabel: 'Shop',
        store: 'shopStore',
        labelAlign: 'right',
        labelStyle: 'margin-top: 2px',
        queryMode: 'local',
        valueField: 'id',
        editable: false,
        displayField: 'name',
        listeners: {
          'select': function() {
              if (this.store.getAt('0')) {
                  me.fireEvent('changeShop');
              }
          }
      }
   }]
});
```

And then simply add it to your window's docked items like you would any other component:

```
initComponent: function () {
   //...
   me.dockedItems = [
      {
          xtype: 'mytoptoolbar'
      }
   ];
   //...
}
```

And the load listener can be added to the store.

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.Base.store.Shop', {
    // ....
    listeners:
    {
        load: function() {
            Ext.ComponentQuery.query("combobox[name='shop-combo']")[0].setValue(...)
        }
    }
```

However, I'd suggest just setting a starting value for the combobox if it's a predictable value. You'll need to add the store to your controller's stores config if you haven't already.

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of this but it doesnt feel like a good solution for me. Doing this i'm extending a class (Ext.toolbar.Toolbar) without adding any new functionality that feels weird. To clearify things up i will extend my question.

Comment: @Manuel I've revised my answer with the new information you've provided. Extending the class allows you to add your own configs and create a custom component that can be easily added to views within your application. I'd recommend it if your goal is splitting up and simplifying your code - there's no requirement for a large scale change to extend a class.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a factory pattern like so:

```
Ext.define('ToolbarFactory', {
alias : 'main.ToolbarFactory',
statics : {

    /**
     * create the toolbar factory
     */
    factory : function() {
        console.log('create the toolbar');
        var toolbar = ....;
        return toolbar;

    }
} 
});
```

Then you can create the Toolbar this way:

```
initComponent: function () {
   //...
   me.dockedItems = [
      ToolbarFactory.factory();
   ];
   //...
}
```

Depending on your build process you may need to add a [requires](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-requires) statement.

Comment: Thank you for this solution.